# Searching withing multiple values always returns 1 result

Tags: php, mysql

I want to retrieve all rows where a certain column contains one of a number of values, but for some reason I always get just one result.

```
$q = "SELECT name FROM products WHERE id IN ('$pid')";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_row($r) ) {
    echo $row[0].'<br>';
}
```

And If i echo out `$q` I get this:

```
SELECT name FROM products WHERE id IN ('2,3,1')
```

I expect to get 3 results returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are treating the `in` value as a string.  I think you are getting a returned value, because the string is being converted back to an integer, which is `2`.  Here is one solution:

```
SELECT name
FROM products
WHERE find_in_set(id, '$pid') > 0;
```

You can also insert the values without the quotes:

```
$q = "SELECT name FROM products WHERE id IN ($pid)";
```

Comment: It is a string, I converted it to a string since it was an array before. When I remove the single quotes I get nothing returned.

Comment: Scratch that, it works! I must've messed something up in the meantime. Your answer (without the quotes) is correct.

Answer (score 0):

remove the single quotes around $pid, use query like this

```
$q = "SELECT name FROM products WHERE id IN ($pid)";
```

Answer (score 0):

The query you need to run is this:

```
SELECT name FROM products WHERE id IN (2,3,1)
```

and -if you don't want to use a prepared statement- this is the correct code:

```
$q = "SELECT name FROM products WHERE id IN ($pid)";
```

your query will return just the products with ID=2 because MySQL automatically casts a string to a number, so

```
2 IN ('2,3,1')
```

becomes TRUE because the strings '2,3,1' is converted to just number 2, while

```
1 IN ('2,3,1')
```

is false.